# How to add custom style to "confirm navigation" dialogs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi it is my first topic on this great site!
I have a problem that I need to dispel.
I need to find a way to customize style of "confirm navigation" dialog box. Can you help me with this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93KW4.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this. The appearance is determined entirely by the browser.

The dialogue is not part of the DOM, it cannot be targeted with CSS. The API for it provides no mechanism to style it.

It can't be replaced with an in-DOM equivalent (since you are blocking navigation, even if it comes from a source outside the page such as the browser refresh button, which can't be done through other methods for security reasons).

Comment: Quentin - thanks for your answer! Please tell me one more thing. Is there an option to disable this dialog?

Comment: @mmstingrayeb — You can remove the unload event handler entirely. Obviously you can't silently prevent a person from leaving your page, that would be very easily abused.

Comment: Ok. So i must leave it.

Comment: Quentin - one more question. If you can please tell me. 

http://imageshack.com/a/img921/7375/1tPv9n.png

Is it possible that the message about the availability of a camera and microphone pull forward?